# Changing number of splits for Hadoop job

Tags: java, hadoop, input, split

I am currently writing code to process a single image using `Hadoop`, so my input is only one file (`.png`). I have working code that will run a job, but instead of running sequential `mappers`, it runs only one `mapper` and never spawns other `mappers`.

I have created my own extensions of the `FileInputFormat` and `RecordReader` classes in order to create (what I thought were) "n" custom `splits` -> "n" `map` tasks.

I've been searching the web like crazy for examples of this nature to learn from, but all I've been able to find are examples which deal with using entire files as a split (meaning exactly one `mapper`) or using a fixed number of lines from a text file (e.g., 3) per `map` task.

What I'm trying to do is send a pair of coordinates `((x1, y1), (x2, y2))` to each `mapper` where the coordinates correspond to the top-left/bottom-right pixels of some rectangle in the image.

Any suggestions/guidance/examples/links to examples would greatly be appreciated.

#### Custom FileInputFormat

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FileInputFormat1 extends FileInputFormat
{
    @Override
    public RecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext taskAttemptContext) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new RecordReader1();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Custom RecordReader

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RecordReader1 extends RecordReader<KeyChunk1, NullWritable> {

    private KeyChunk1 key;
    private NullWritable value;

    private ImagePreprocessor IMAGE;

    public RecordReader1()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return IMAGE.getProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public KeyChunk1 getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public NullWritable getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        boolean gotNextValue = IMAGE.hasAnotherChunk();

        if (gotNextValue)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                key = new KeyChunk1();
            }
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = NullWritable.get();
            }

            int[] data = IMAGE.getChunkIndicesAndIndex();
            key.setChunkIndex(data[2]);
            key.setStartRow(data[0]);
            key.setStartCol(data[1]);
            key.setChunkWidth(data[3]);
            key.setChunkHeight(data[4]);
        }
        else
        {
            key = null;
            value = null;
        }

        return gotNextValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext taskAttemptContext) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration config = taskAttemptContext.getConfiguration();
        IMAGE = new ImagePreprocessor(
                config.get("imageName"),
                config.getInt("v_slices", 1),
                config.getInt("h_slices", 1),
                config.getInt("kernel_rad", 2),
                config.getInt("grad_rad", 1),
                config.get("hdfs_address"),
                config.get("local_directory")
        );
    }
}
```

#### ImagePreprocessor Class (Used in custom RecordReader - only showing necessary information)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImagePreprocessor {

    private String filename;
    private int num_v_slices;
    private int num_h_slices;
    private int minSize;

    private int width, height;

    private int chunkWidth, chunkHeight;
    private int indexI, indexJ;

    String hdfs_address, local_directory;

    public ImagePreprocessor(String filename, int num_v_slices, int num_h_slices, int kernel_radius, int gradient_radius,
                             String hdfs_address, String local_directory) throws IOException{
        this.hdfs_address = hdfs_address;
        this.local_directory = local_directory;

        // all "validate" methods throw errors if input data is invalid

        checkValidFilename(filename);
        checkValidNumber(num_v_slices, "vertical strips");
        this.num_v_slices = num_v_slices;
        checkValidNumber(num_h_slices, "horizontal strips");
        this.num_h_slices = num_h_slices;
        checkValidNumber(kernel_radius, "kernel radius");
        checkValidNumber(gradient_radius, "gradient radius");

        this.minSize = 1 + 2 * (kernel_radius + gradient_radius);

        getImageData(); // loads image and saves width/height to class variables
        validateImageSize();

        chunkWidth = validateWidth((int)Math.ceil(((double)width) / num_v_slices));
        chunkHeight = validateHeight((int)Math.ceil(((double)height) / num_h_slices));

        indexI = 0;
        indexJ = 0;

    }

    public boolean hasAnotherChunk()
    {
        return indexI < num_h_slices;
    }

    public int[] getChunkIndicesAndIndex()
    {
        int[] ret = new int[5];
        ret[0] = indexI;
        ret[1] = indexJ;
        ret[2] = indexI*num_v_slices + indexJ;
        ret[3] = chunkWidth;
        ret[4] = chunkHeight;

        indexJ += 1;
        if (indexJ >= num_v_slices)
        {
            indexJ = 0;
            indexI += 1;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please add your codes too so that others can help you quickly

Comment: Done; I stripped some methods out from the last class since they aren't really needed for this specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override method `public InputSplit[] getSplits(JobConf job, int numSplits)` in your `FileInputFormat1` class. Create  your own class based on `InputSplit` with rectangle coordinates, so inside `FileInputFormat` you can get this information to return correct key/value pairs to mapper.
Probably implementation of `getSplits` in `FileInputFormat` could help you [see here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#line.312).

Comment: I think the versions of Hadoop we're using differ slightly, but let me know if I'm understanding this correctly: `getSplits` should return  a list/array (version dependent) of some `InputSplit` class. Each of the elements in this list is sent to my custom `RecordReader` which should then read the corresponding data and create the key/value pair needed for a single mapper?

Comment: that's right, instance of `InputSplit` is passed to method `initialize` of `RecordReader`, and this is a place where you can configure your `ImagePreprocessor`. Number of input splits is a number of map tasks in job.

Comment: Got it. Everything's working fine now. (I also had to make sure that my `InputSplit` class implemented `Writable`.) Thank you for your help!